# pointing a datarow towards a string variable?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I was just wondering on how i go about displaying the balance for the account that belongs to the selected cardNumber. I have used the following code on form 1 to drag variables holding the selected cardnumber and the accoutnnumber that belongs to that cardnumber on form1 to form2.

```
       int index = comboBoxCardNumber.SelectedIndex;
        DataRow dpin = dataSet11.Tables["ATMCards"].Rows[index];
        String pin = dpin.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        String AccountNumber = dpin.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();

                Form2 frm2;
                frm2 = new Form2();
                frm2.accountNumber = AccountNumber;
                frm2.CardNumber = index;
                frm2.Owner = this;
                frm2.ShowDialog();
```

As the code above shows the CardNumber holds the selected card and the accountNumber shows the accountNumber for that selected card. When i try creating a new datarow on form two i cant figure out how to point the datarow towards the accoutnumber that belongs to the selected card. Heres the code i have used for form 2:

```
    public int CardNumber;
    public String accountNumber;       

       private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlDataAdapterBalance.Fill(dataSet2Balance1.Accounts);            
    }

    private void btnShowBalance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        DataRow accountId = dataSet2Balance1.Tables["Accounts"].Rows[CardNumber];
        String accountNumber = accountId.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();

        richTextBox1.AppendText(accountNumber);

    }
```

My question is how do you point the datarow to the string variable accountNumber rather than the selected CardNumber?Rather than pointing the datarow to the variable CardNumber i need it to use the accountnumber that belongs tot hat card any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to filter your `DataTable` to get the row that contains the account number.  Use a `Select` on the `DataTable`:

```
DataRow[] rows = dataSet2Balance1.Tables["Accounts"].Select("AccountNumber=" + accountNumber);
Console.WriteLine(rows[0]["AccountNumber"].ToString());
```

If I didn't understand correctly, please let me know and I'll update accordingly.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I used the following code you gave me 
            DataRow [] rows = dataSet2Balance1.Tables["Accounts"].Select(accountNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(rows[0]["accountNumber"].ToString());
and i get the following error message:
Filter expression '12345680' does not evaluate to a Boolean term.

The 12345680 is the account number i need to find the balance for.

Comment: What you pass in to `Select` is not a variable - it's essentially a WHERE clause from SQL without the "WHERE".  So you would want your call to `Select` to look something like: `.Select("AccountNumber = " + accountNumber)`.  I'm not sure what your AccountNumber column is named, but you would need to include that.  I hope this makes sense.  Let me know and I'll try to be more clear.  (It's early and I haven't had coffee yet.)

Comment: Ive pointed the data row to the account ID column  
DataRow[] rows = dataSet2Balance1.Tables["Accounts"].Select("accountId=" + accountNumber);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(rows[0]["accountId"].ToString());

the richtextbox displays the correct account number for each of the selected cards i just need to be able to print their balance now, Any ideas , sorry for constantly bothering you mate

Comment: Definitely not a bother - I'm glad I can help.  :)  `rows[0]` contains the entire row from the `DataTable`. So you can get the balance by referencing the column name for the balance.  Without knowing your column name, it may look like: `richTextBox2.AppendText(rows[0]["balance"].ToString());`.